# ToDictionary throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a `Dictionary<int,int>` that will have 329734 elements.  When I try to create an in-memory dictionary mapping a unique integer column to the integer Id, the code

```
var dict = ctx.MyEntity.ToDictionary(e => e.SomethingUnique, e => e.Id);
```

throws

> OutOfMemoryException

There should be ample memory to create dictionary of those two integers.  What is happening here, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

The entire object is being returned, even though only two fields are ever consumed.  Because there are many properties in the object, the runtime runs out of available memory.

This can be avoided using a projection

```
var dict = ctx.MyEntity
              .Select(e => new { SomethingUnique = e.SomethingUnique,
                                 Id = e.Id })
              .ToDictionary(e => e.SomethingUnique, e => e.Id);
```

Even if you do not run out of memory, using a projection is more efficient.